# Get All DLLS For A Process

Tags: c#, .net, dll, process

I would like to get a list of all the dlls loaded for a given Process. I am currently using **.NET Framework 4.0**. I am aware that there is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/546430/system-diagnostics-process-modules-doesnt-include-managed-dlls) when trying to access all managed dlls through the Process.Modules property. (Only lists the unmanaged dlls). I need a way to programmatically retrieve all of these dlls.

```
 Process[] myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess");
 if(myProcess.Count() > 0) 
 {
      foreach (ProcessModule processModule in myProcess[0].Modules)
      //get information
 }
```

EDIT: The process I am interested in is not in the current AppDomain.

Comment: check out : `AppDomain.GetAssemblies`

Comment: @AppDeveloper i think he wants to get the assemblies of another process and not the own process using AppDomain

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If my process is not running in the current AppDomain however, I do not believe this will work.

Comment: Do you know the name or Id of the process you want to inspect?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli Yes I have a handle on the Process in question. I use Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess") method to retrieve it.

Comment: @Matthew - but u can easily know how many app domain are there in your process!

Comment: So you're saying that when you call Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess").Modules you're only getting unmanaged DLLs but you want managed ones as well.  Is this correct?

Comment: I think the fact that your code snippet uses GetCurrentProcess() is causing some confusion.

Comment: @AppDeveloper I am a bit confused as to what you mean. If I understand correctly, a Process may contain one or many AppDomains. Can you maybe elaborate on what you are suggesting?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli yes that is exactly what the problem is. Sorry for the confusion, updated code to hopefully clear up the goal of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am aware that there is a bug

No, that's not a bug.  It was an intentional design change in CLR v4, Microsoft did not keep that a secret.  Previous versions of the CLR made an effort to emulate loaded assemblies as though they were unmanaged DLLs.  But that just stopped making sense when they implemented the side-by-side in-process CLR versioning feature.  It's gone and won't come back.

This isn't exactly a major problem, getting the list of loaded assemblies in another process is well supported by the debugging interface.  ICorDebugAppDomain::EnumerateAssemblies() is the ticket.  Well, not exactly as easy to use as Process.Modules.  Use the [MDbg sample](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282) to find out how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Can you please look at my other question regarding MDbg? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877213/mdbg-debuggers-protocol-is-incompatible-with-the-debuggee).