# MDbg - Debugger's Protocol Is Incompatible With The Debuggee

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I am using MDbg to retrieve a list of all my assemblies listed inside a process' App Domain. Whenever I try to attach a process to the MDbgEngine I receive the following exception message:

> The debugger's protocol is incompatible with the debuggee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013134B)

Am I missing something or calling the method incorrectly? I am using .NET Framework 4.0 and the MDbg core reference is taken from \Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\MdbgCore.dll.

Code:

```
MDbgProcess process;
MDbgEngine mDbgEngine = new MDbgEngine();
process = mDbgEngine.Attach(myProcess.Id); // this line causes the error
foreach (CorAppDomain appDomain in process.AppDomains)
{
   foreach (CorAssembly assembly in appDomain.Assemblies)
   {
      //get assembly information
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using the .NET 2 version of MDbg or the bitness is wrong.

Comment: A took a while for MDbg to support the .NET 4 debugger protocol version, it wouldn't have made it in the SDK version 7.  I already gave you a link to the version 4 sample.

Comment: @Matthew Older post but similar requirement then my need. I solved it meanwhile thanks to your post and hints from Hans Passant. If you still need it here is my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803406/how-to-list-check-existance-of-managed-net-dlls-in-dllhost-exe/40805116#40805116

Answer (score 0):

The mdbg locations are at:

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Bin/

for the 3.x version of the Framework and is at:

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/

for the 4.x version of the Framework. Thank you. Good day.