# Get .NET Assemblies Info on process (like Sysinternals Process Explorer) via Code (C# or PowerShell)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, process, assemblies

In Sysinternals Process Explorer there exists a tab ".NET Assemblies".

This tab is only shown in the properties for processes that actually use .NET Assemblies.

How can I get the same information on any running process using PowerShell or C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it looks as if that code is meant for 'Self Reflection' of a Process. I want to read out info on other processes currently running.

Comment: Ok, then you can use MDBG to attach to that process and analize it's assemblies. But maybe it's an overkill and there is some easier way.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863369/get-all-dlls-for-a-process) I've realized that maybe there is no easy way to get what you need. So let's go with MDBG to solve your challenge for **managed** processes:

```
        _engine = new MDbgEngine();
        _engine.Attach(p.Id, RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion());
        _engine.Processes.Active.Go().WaitOne();
        foreach (MDbgAppDomain appDomain in _engine.Processes.Active.AppDomains) {
            foreach (CorAssembly assembly in appDomain.CorAppDomain.Assemblies) {
                Console.WriteLine(assembly.Name);
            }

        }
```

You will have to using MDBG package from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine/):   `<package id="Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine" version="1.4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />`

Comment: Thanks for that input.

I used that and was able to some extent to gather the assemblies. For some processes ( like chrome) it seems to hang.

Comment: @TimoSperisen As I mentioned in response it works only for .NET managed processes, while Chrome as far as I know is written mainly in C++ and not running on CLR. What does the tab  ".NET Assemblies" shows for chrome in Sysinternals Process Explorer ?

Comment: @TimoSperisen To avoid hunging you may try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080161/5246145) (never tested it)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That example seemed to work better!

Answer (score 1):

[ClrMD (Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime)](https://github.com/microsoft/clrmd) could be used.

An example of Powershell usage:

- download [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime nupkg file](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) and unpack
  it to get Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.dll
- get an ID of the target process
- run script below using the process ID and correct path to Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.dll

  ```
   [int]$targetProcessId=12345
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('.\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.dll')

   $dataTarget = [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.DataTarget]::AttachToProcess($targetProcessId, 1) #AttachFlags.Noninvasive
   try
   {
       $clrRuntime = $dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime()

       foreach ($domain in $clrRuntime.AppDomains) {
           Write-Host "Domain ID: " $domain.Id ", Name: " $domain.Name

           foreach ($clrModule in $domain.Modules) {           
               Write-Host "`t`t" $clrModule.Name
           }
       }
   }
   finally
   {
       $dataTarget.Dispose()
   }
  ```